# C program termenats after reading file

Tags: c, file, codeblocks

I am trying to read file in C language and store the data in arrays , It works well except I do not want the program to finish after closing the file

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"
char TimeDat[24][8] ;
float TempArr [2][24];
float HumiArr[24];
float MotionArr[6][24];
void ReadDataFile(char *location,char device_location [10],int line);
void get_menu();


 int main( )
{

while(1)
{
   get_menu();

}

return 0;
}

void get_menu()
{

 char chosen_name [10] ;
        int menu_option;
    printf("Choose your task : \n");
    printf("1 - Read files by name  : \n");
    scanf ("%d",&menu_option);

 if (menu_option==1)
 {
   printf("Enter Your file name : Bedroom , Kitchen , LivingRoom  \n");
   scanf ("%s",&chosen_name);
       if (strcmp(chosen_name,"Bedroom") == 0)
              {
              char * Bedroom_file_location="Bedroom.txt";
              ReadDataFile(Bedroom_file_location ,"Bedroom",24);

              }
              else  if (strcmp(chosen_name,"Kitchen") == 0)
              {
              char * Kitchen_file_location="Kitchen.txt";
              ReadDataFile(Kitchen_file_location ,"Bedroom",24);

              }
              else if (strcmp(chosen_name,"LivingRoom") == 0)
              {
              char * LivingRoom_file_location="LivingRoom.txt";
              ReadDataFile(LivingRoom_file_location ,"Bedroom",24);

              }

 }
 else if (menu_option==2 )
 {


 }
}

void ReadDataFile(char *location,char device_location [10],int line) {
    printf("this is a %s \n",device_location);
int read_status=0;
int t,k;
FILE *fp; // assign to the file location
fp = fopen(location, "r");
if(fp == NULL)
{
printf("Error!\n");
//exit(1);
}

 t=0;
while(line--){
fscanf(fp, "%s", &TimeDat[t]);
fscanf(fp, "%f%f", &TempArr[t][0], &TempArr[t][1]);
fscanf(fp, "%f", &HumiArr[t]);
for ( k=0; k<6; k++)

{
  fscanf(fp,"%f", &MotionArr[t][k]);

}
 printf("  :%s ",TimeDat[t]);
printf(" : %f  , %f ",TempArr[t][0],TempArr[t][1]);
printf(" : %f ",HumiArr[t]);
printf("  : %f  , %f  , %f , %f , %f , %f",MotionArr[t][0],MotionArr[t][1],MotionArr[t][2],MotionArr[t][3],MotionArr[t][4],MotionArr[t][5]);
printf("  \n");
    t++;
}


fclose(fp);
main();

}
```

my output is 100% correct but i am getting this message :

```
Process returned -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)   execution time : 6.531 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Output img [image: output after reading the file and close it]

I am tring to get back to the menu so the user could open another file for example or do some other options.
I will appreciate your help
Thanks in advence

Comment: don't know if it will fix your problem, but don't call `main`. Let `ReadDataFile` return, `get_menu` return, then you're back in `main`, back in your infinite loop. Calling `main` in `ReadDataFile` will never let any of these functions return, and your process will continue to consume memory and stack space.

Comment: Your `chosen_name` character array is too small.  The longest string you expect is `LivingRoom`, which is 10 characters.  But there's a `\0` put at the end by `scanf`, possibly contaminating the following variable (`menu_option`).  Plus, if somebody types an even longer string, `scanf` will mess up your stack something fierce.

Comment: I've tried to call get_menu after closed the file "fclose(fp);" but i had the same result

Comment: definitely it is something to do with file reading process

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]
Basicly the problem was because of 2D array

it should be :

```
char TimeDat[24][8] ;
float TempArr [24][2];
float HumiArr[24];
float MotionArr[24][6];
```

Not

```
char TimeDat[24][8] ;
float TempArr [2][24];
float HumiArr[24];
float MotionArr[6][24];
```